# Asp.Net Jpeg Compression

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, jpeg, image-compression

I am saving original picture and its thumbnail but the thumbnail size is bigger than the original.

```
if (fu_photo.HasFile)
{
    fu_photo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../media/" + fu_photo.FileName));

    Bitmap orgimg = new Bitmap(fu_photo.FileContent);

    double orgWidth = orgimg.Width;
    double orgHeight = orgimg.Height;
    double orgRatio = orgWidth / orgHeight;
    int newWidth = 256;
    int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(newWidth) / orgRatio);

    Bitmap newimg = new Bitmap(orgimg, newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics gimg = Graphics.FromImage(newimg);

    gimg.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gimg.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    gimg.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    gimg.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    //   gimg.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    gimg.DrawImage(newimg, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

    newimg.Save(Server.MapPath("../media/256_" + fu_photo.FileName));

    orgimg.Dispose();
    newimg.Dispose();
    gimg.Dispose();

}
```

This is my code. I tried it with a 680x382px 93kB photo. It saved the original one at 93kB but it saved the thumbnail one at 256x144px and 97kB!
When I tried to save with Photoshop at high quality and 256x144px it saved it at 18kB.
How can I reduce the image file size?

Answer (score 0):

because you map a low quality to high quality image, 
and how about this?

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(ServerPatch + fileName);        
System.Drawing.Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(_Width,_Height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
thumb.Save(ServerPatch + "/thumb/" + fileName);
```